# Replace value in cell as cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner at VBA, I am trying to modify a code written by someone else.
I want to replace `C22` in the below line with variable value stored in cell `B19`.

Code:

```
Set Emp = Sheets("programme summary").Range("C22:C" & LR)
```

The value in `C22` is like "B12". Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `Set Emp = Sheets("programme summary").Range(Sheets("programme summary").Range("B19") & ":C" & LR)`??  (Maybe update the question to explain better what is in cell B19, i.e. is it something like "C32", or is it a number that you want to append to a `"C"` to create a cell reference, or something else.)

Comment: The value in B19 is like C32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to set the range `Emp` to commence from the cell *referred to* by cell B19, you can use something like

```
Set Emp = Sheets("programme summary").Range(Sheets("programme summary").Range("B19").Value & ":C" & LR)
```

---

Explanation:

The `Sheets("programme summary").Range("B19").Value` part of the statement retrieves the value in cell B19 of the "programme summary" sheet (perhaps that might be `"C32"`), and then a range is formed by concatenating that with the string generated by `":C" & LR`, giving something like `"C32:C789"` (assuming `LR` contains the value `789`).

This new string is used in the remaining part of the statement which effectively becomes

```
Set Emp = Sheets("programme summary").Range("C32:C789")
```